# When I try to install vscode, snapd shows error code 400

Tags: software-center, security, snap

I've just tried installing vscode from the software center.

Here's what happened:

- I was asked to register to Ubuntu One.
- I was asked for authentication, in Turkish. This is a new Entroware laptop with Ubuntu preinstalled.
- I typed in my system password.
- I got this:

  ```
  Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
   snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request
  ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

vscode is a 'classic' snap which unfortunately cannot currently be installed in software center. However, you can install it from the command line via `snap install vscode --classic`.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: thanks, it works for Atom too but I'm wonderin that if it is not possible to install this snap package with software center, then why the software center shows this snap package in the homepage of itself?

Comment: @InterestingKnox that was probably a mistake and it looks like it's gone now

Answer (score 0):

You can add repository from command line and then install from commandline as mentioned on [Visual Studio Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux). Following are the commands:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
```

And then run following commands to complete installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code # or code-insiders
```

Comment: And when you're finished doing that sit back, relax and watch while your system gets hosed. Visual Code is useless without installing extensions and you trust that thing to put the extensions wherever it wants. I trust the snap `--classic`option to do a better job of sandboxing Visual Studio Code than that because at least it's planned.