# snapd return status code 400: Bad request

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

Whenever I try to install any software from ubuntu software centre, I receive a message saying "cannot do that"[image]

click on the above link to see the image that I get

When I choose to download it from terminal it says:

```
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_snwh_pulp_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What do I suppose to do and first of all please tell me why this error is occurring?

Comment: refer to this , it seems u too have a 'classic' snap issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/923021/when-i-try-to-install-vscode-snapd-returns-error-code-400

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in terminal

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

And Then

```
sudo apt update
```

I think your `/var/lib/apt/lists/` files are corrupted So You Can delete them to regenerate them.

Comment: when i entered your first command it says:                                                                             unable to resolve, and further rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/*': No such file or directory.
what to do?

Comment: ok.Then Manually delete all files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` and then do `sudo apt update`

Comment: That actually worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04!

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually caused by trying to install software that is packaged as a "classic snap" rather than a normal snap or a deb package.  Classic snaps cannot be installed using the Ubuntu Software application due to the way they are packaged (why they even show up in Ubuntu Software is a mystery to me).  You can install them using the `snap` command-line tool.  First, search for the app (i.e. for slack):

```
snap search slack
```

The notes column will say `classic` for classic snaps.  These are the kind that must be installed using the command line:

```
sudo snap install slack
```

this will warn you about the security risks of a classic snap and advise you to append `--classic` if you understand them:

```
sudo snap install slack --classic
```

#### Sources:

- [When I try to install vscode, snapd shows error code 400](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923021/when-i-try-to-install-vscode-snapd-shows-error-code-400)
- https://itsfoss.com/snapd-error-ubuntu/