# Where is the install location for the "snap" download tool?

Tags: software-installation, snap

In trying to download vscode from the Ubuntu software application, I ran into the following error:

```
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
 snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request
```

After Googling this error I took the advice given by this following link:

[When I try to install vscode, snapd returns error code 400](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923021/when-i-try-to-install-vscode-snapd-returns-error-code-400?newreg=3b466796b92c4298839ff80d0735d0de)

which led me to running the following command in my terminal:

```
snap install vscode --classic
```

That command worked and all, but now I can't find where and how to start vscode on my machine.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: According to https://askubuntu.com/a/917290/158442, classic mode snaps are installed to your home directory.

Comment: @muru I've looked there already and I don't see a vscode sub directory

Comment: Looks like it's wrong. I run `sudo snap install vscode --classic`, and it was installed to `/snap`, and since `/snap/bin` is in my `PATH`, I could just run `vscode` in a terminal. It also showed up in the Dash after that.

Comment: That other answer says the _extensions_ will be in your home dir. Probably in the snap dir.

Answer (score 17):

I added `/snap/bin` to `$PATH`. That worked for opening VS Code from the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

After `sudo snap install vscode --classic`, I'm able to start up VS Code by searching 'code' in the Dash and clicking on the Launcher item that comes up (if this isn't working (note that it might take a while for VS Code to start up), make a topic on the issue [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snap) and tag wimpress in your post or email the address in the `contact` field of `snap info vscode`).

You can also start VS Code with `snap run vscode`.

Answer (score 1):

Using CentOS7.9, I was able to install it as (root user) and start it using:

```
        # install snap tool:
        yum install snapd -y
        systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
        ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
        # install Visual Studio Code through Snap:
        snap install code --classic
```

Start vscode: `snap run code`